# how to get beta function in rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, beta

I need to use beta function Beta(a, b) in my calculation in Rcpp. A simple code example I wrote is here:

```
cppFunction('double getbeta(double a, double b){
  double res = beta(a, b);
  return res;
}')
```

But I got an error in R saying that

> no matching function for call to 'beta'

Is it because we cannot use Beta function in Rcpp? If we could, is there the corresponding function

```
lbeta
```

can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `R::` namespace for the scalar-value functions (and `Rcpp::` for vectorised sugar functions):

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction('double getbeta(double a, double b){
+   double res = R::beta(a, b);
+   return res;
+ }')
R> getbeta(1.0, 2.0)
[1] 0.5
R>
```